# Separating a 2D Array into Regions bounded by a Continuous Line

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am a beginner hobbyist programmer in my first year of college. Recently I've been obsessed with the puzzle game "The Witness", for its minimalist yet surprisingly difficult puzzles. As a passion project I'm attempting to recreate just the Puzzle element of the game for others to enjoy.

**THE GAME**

[This is How the Game Looks So Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay8IB.png)

Essentially, you have a white path that is controlled by the user, and you must navigate that path through the grid, splitting the grid into region consisting of black and white tiles. Each region must have only white or only black tiles.
I've posted a picture of how the project looks so far, with a solved puzzle.

**THE PROBLEM**

I cannot for the life of me figure out a function to split the grid into regions as shown in the image. The Path is a 1D array of x and y coordinates of each point in the path. when its done, it should be at the top right corner of the grid at (cols,rows). This is assuming the lower left corner is (0,0).

```
Path = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...,[cols,rows]]
```

each Puzzle has n rows and n columns, so id like a function getRegions(path, cols, rows) that takes in the path, and the rows and columns, and outputs an array like this

```
arrayWithRegions=
[[2,3,3,2],
 [2,2,2,2],
 [1,1,1,2],
 [1,1,1,2]]
```

where each square is marked as being in a distinct region based on the boundaries set by the path and the outer border. The example is how the array would look for the puzzle in the image provided. (disregard the black and white blocks, they don't matter right now)

I'd appreciate any sort of help or even a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just execute [Flood fill algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) using path line and field edges as borders.

Choose any unmarked cell (for example - left bottom one), start flood fill with region mark 1, traverse all possible cells. Then find another unmarked cell, start fill with region mark 2 and so on.

The simplest recursive implementation of FF algo and sequential search of unmarked cells should work nicely for small size of your field.

Comment: Dude you are the man. You've saved my life, and your explanation of how to implement it is beautifully intuitive. I also really like this algorithm, I had never heard of it before but it seems very useful for border detection. I'll follow up with the code once I implement it. Your help was much appreciated.